# Load wordpress theme class first before plugin classes

Tags: wordpress, plugins, themes

I have Chico class in Wordpress Theme.
I am calling it in functions.php

```
if(!function_exists('chico_settings')):
function chico_settings() {
    $chico_settings = &Chico::getInstance('Menu_Chico');
}
endif;
add_action('init', 'chico_settings');
```

We are going to make a new plugin that also wants to use Chico class.
But when I call it in plugin, it says:

```
Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class Chico in /var/www/chics/wp-content/themes/chico/app/chico.php on line 4
```

Is there a way to load theme first before plugin?

Comment: `Cannot redeclare class` it mean you've already declare class `Chico`

Comment: Yes. Inside the Theme i am using Chico class as static.
If only i can make theme load first before the plugin, i won't need to redeclare Chico class in Plugin.

Comment: I found no solution to this. I just made a child-theme.